# Rest service call using getjson and jquery in phonegap (android)

Tags: android, cordova

index.html

```
$(document).ready(function() {
alert("load");
window.EXTERNALLINK.loadExternalLink("http://127.0.0.1:8080/v1/service");
$.getJSON("http://127.0.0.1:8080/v1/service", function() {
alert("success");
})
.success(function() { alert("second success"); })
.error(function() { alert("error"); });

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);

});

function onDeviceReady(){
     navigator.notification.alert("PhoneGap is working");

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="us.service"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />

<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"
    />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission       android:name="android.permission.
    ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS"    />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />   
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />   
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE">
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_VPN_SERVICE">
    </uses-permission>

    <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".portalActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
   </application>

    </manifest>
```

cordova.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cordova>
   <access origin="http://127.0.0.1:8080/*" />
   <log level="DEBUG"/>

 </cordova>
```

I am unable to call the rest service from using getjson and above are the configurations that I made. Please let me know if something else is to be added

below is my rest service call

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/v1")
public class ReportController  
{


@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET,
        value = "/service" )
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody
public String status()
{
    return "success";

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if any of these works or not

Change access origin to `<access origin="*" />`

Change JSON call to this

```
$.getJSON("http://127.0.0.1:8080/v1/service?callback=?", function() {
    alert("success");
})​;
```

Also check whether your `http://127.0.0.1:8080/v1/service` is accessible from browser directly or not. Use chrome and check the response data and corresponding datatype.

Comment: thanks a lot guys for your comments but my issue got resolved........the configurations and stuff was correct but I was using older version of jquery due to which getjson was not executing and after adding jquery 1.4.5 it got resolved.....thanks a lot once agaqin

Comment: i am abe to access http://127.0.0.1:8080/v1/service from m browser but not able to access the same using my ip address

Comment: if i am using callback=? i am not able o call the service not sure what is the exact issue

Comment: sorry so is the address still `127.0.0.1` or changed to something else

Comment: I am unable to access the url if I include callback=? do I have to write any thing in the service call

Comment: Can someone help me out I am getting response as null and don't even see in the server logs that service is called

Comment: you will not be able to use `127.0.0.1` from android as it is a loopback address and will point to android itself. Try using the real ip address of the machine on which your service is running

Comment: but using my ip address i am unable to call the service......Can I use localhost instead of that

Comment: i have got it working with real ip address. If i use localhost it gives timeout error so it may not be possible

Comment: i have put my example at this gist https://gist.github.com/2039298. Also check what your server returns as a jsonp response, my test server always return data in `jsonpcallback` callback so i have to create a separate method to for that

Comment: hey dhaval can you even please mail me ur service call class code please

Comment: i have put the service code in gist, it is a simple java servlet

Comment: @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET,
            value = "/terminal" )
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @ResponseBody
    public String terminal()
    {
        return "jasdknsd";

     }

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
 alert("load");
 
 $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/v1/terminal", 
 
   function(data) {
  //var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    //alert("success"+evalJSON(data));
    alert("message"+data);
  });

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);

});

Comment: the above code is for service call and calling service using getjson am I missing something and I am getting alert box as message null...it means i am able to call the service rite

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this on a phone or the simulator? 127.0.0.1 probably will not resolve. Either use the hostname of your computer or the actual IP address.
If you are running it on a phone make sure your phone is on the same network as the computer.